# Evaluating a single expression on a remote machine

Tags: remote-access

I have Mathematica installed on my MacBook. I also have access to a remote Linux server with many more nodes and virtually unlimited disk space and memory and Mathematica installed. I can in principle `ssh -X` to it and run Mathematica. For the purposes of the question, I don't want to copy everything to the remote machine, and work there.

What I need to do is to run a single function evaluation `F[x,y,z]`, which is very computationally heavy, on the remote machine because the remote machine is much more powerful, can run more nodes in parallel, etc.

I guess what I could do in principle is to dump `x, y, z`, and the definition of `F` to a `*.mx` file, `scp` it to the server, `ssh` to it, load Mathematica, load the file, run it, dump the output to a file, `scp` the file with the output back, and load the file with the output at the local machine.

Is there a way to automate it? Or is there a much better way to do what I want? I would like to have an option of evaluating `EvaluateRemotely[F,x,y,z]` or something like that. It is fine if I need to manually type login/password for the remote machine but not more than that. TIA

Comment: See this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ConnectToARemoteKernel.html